# Is it possible to do negative loc in the NSMakeRange?

Tags: ios, nsrange

Is it possible to do negative loc in the NSMakeRange?

```
NSString *string = @"abc";
NSString *myString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(-1, 1)];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

`location` and `length` are [unsigned integers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW23) :

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
    NSUInteger location;
    NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

and also, `NSMakeRange` function is [defined](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BAJDGHDI) as follow :

```
NSRange NSMakeRange (
    NSUInteger loc,
    NSUInteger len
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible, but in fact it will no sense since negative value will translated to another  very big positive value.

```
NSUInteger loc = -1; // equal to 4294967295
```

1.So, you are in need of a very long string.
2.So, you need to invert your negative value to enormous big value in order to make your example worked

```
NSString *string = @"abc";
NSRange r1 = NSMakeRange(-NSUIntegerMax, 1);
NSString *myString = [string substringWithRange:r1];
NSLog(@"%@",myString);
```